# How to read lines from line-number n to line-number m of a file?

Tags: java, file, readline

Is there a way that I could read lines from line number n to line number m from a file?

To put it other way, I have a file with over 100k entries. I would like load 10k lines at once, process them and then load next 10k lines, so as to run with limited memory resources. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just use a ``BufferedReader``?

Comment: If you're using `readLine`, you're using `BufferedReader` already, right?

Comment: Use [LineNumberReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html), which is a `BufferedReader` with line number support.

Comment: @Jean Logeart  
Yes , I am already using a BufferedReader , but to fetch the second batch , i end up starting from the beginning of the file and skip all the lines that are already fetched. This is a costly operation and moreover when the batch size is small and the total lines are too many , this would create a lot of overhead in terms of time. Is there any way to avoid this.

Comment: @Andreas : Could you please give me an example  like how can i fetch lines from line n to line m by using LineNumberReader along with BufferedReader? I can go to a line using LineNumberReader . Could you please tell me how to fetch lines from that line using BufferedReader without skipping all the lines prior to line n?

Comment: @sujith that's impossible, because a file is just a pointer to the beginning of the file. Take a closer look at my answer, that's what you want

Comment: @Dici  Thank you for the answer. The solution provided by you works perfectly for my use-case.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot start reading at an arbitrary line, but that's not what you say in the second part of your question. What you want is the following, if it's fine to hold the resource for the whole process :

```
int batchSize = 10000;
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath())) {
    boolean eof = false;
    while (!eof) {
        List<String> batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
        for (int i=0 ; i<batchSize ; i++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (eof = line == null) break;
            batch.add(line);
        }
        processBatch(batch);
    }
}
```

If you want to release the resource as soon as possible, it might be a better idea to have a *producer* splitting the files by batches of 10 000 lines while a *consumer* process them in order. This can be achieved very easily with two threads and a `BlockingQueue<File>`.

Comment: Hi,
The first batch could be fetched easily but i would end up skipping all the lines in the already fetched batches to fetch the next batch . This would result in time delay.
I am actually trying to fetch all the lines from file in batches of  10k lines at once.

Comment: @Dici I find it better to clarify `(eof = line == null)` with an extra parenthesis: `(eof = (line == null))`

Comment: @Dici Inline assignment is generally bad, so maybe `if (line == null) { eof = true; break; }` is better.